# Loading WSI slide images to python and converting images to array

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have been new to WSI image processing and have been trying load images to python. I was successfull in loading slide images but it is not getting converted to an array for further processing. any help is appreciated. Following is the code i used

filenames = os.listdir("C:/Users/DELL/Downloads/dataset1")
X_train= np.array(filenames)

following is the output i get instead of an array of numbers representing an image
'TCGA-BA-4074-01A-01-BS1.9c51e4d0-cb30-412a-995a-97ac4f860a87.svs'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use specialized libraries for the reading of WSI image. Check these:

- [slideio](http://slideio.com/)
- [openslide](https://openslide.org/)

Keep in mind that normally the WSI slides are too large to load them
in the memory in the original resolution. You can load them partially or on the low resolutions. Both of the libraries support such a functionality.